# Symfony - how to get data from select html tag in view

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, drop-down-menu, request

I am learning Symfony so I am testing various ways to work with database. The idea is to make select dropdown list that contains data from table in database. Each option in select returns value that is id of column from table. Dropdown list is defined in View in this way ('find_res' in action is route to controller):

```
<form action="{{ path('find_res') }}" method="POST" name="formpt">
       <select name="patientId">
        {% for patient in patients %}       
           {{dump(patient)}}
           <option value="{{patient.id}}">{{patient.lastname}}{{patient.firstname}}</option><br />
        {% endfor %}
      </select>   
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Find results</button>
  </form>
```

so that for chosen patient.id it should show results in table which is defined in code bellow this as standard html table.

In controller method I created list of all patients from table in database and sent it as parameter to this view. And that works just fine. Also, I would not get into details how query is built because the problem is that any $request I try does not return anything, just null. I tried:

```
$request->request->get('patientId'); //returns null always
$request->get('patientId'); //also null
```

I even tried to give name to form in view like for instance 'formpt' and then tried it with:

```
$request->request->get('formpt')['patientId'];
```

still nothing. This test code:

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'  ) {
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($request->request->get('patientId'));
        exit;
  }
```

always returns NULL or string(0) "" for whatever I put in "dump".

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You can't use `<br>` in a `select` element, also you are dumping some data (`{{dump(patient)}}`) inside it. Try it again after fixing your HTML.

Comment: Are you deliberately not using the [form component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)?

Comment: @prehfeldt cleaned <select> element. Still the same problem.

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, I tried to put form in view, it seems easier to define the look you want. and I need just one dropdown with data from one table.

Comment: Maybe try this 
{{ form_start(form) }}
<select>...</select>
{{ form_end() }}
So you can also use the csrf token to protect your form.

Comment: @Mz1907 That's the part I don't understand. That would not be standard form, just one select list that returns id and no text fields. So, how it would that form/dropdown list look like if defined in controller?

Comment: In your controller you get a list of many patients (from DB) and send it to the view ? Right ? you can also send a form to the view. 
If you send the PatientForm in the view you can use {{ form_start(form) }} <select>...</select> {{ form_end() }} .... so you will have a simple form with only a select list. .... Another solution here:  try to send the form from controller to the view, use {{ form_start(form) }} and  then try to see (in google inspector)  what will be the form name attribute .. so you can use that name attribute instead of name="formpt"

Comment: Ups, the issue was where I wasn't expecting it. My getid method for patient did not have a return. Now it works. Still, I have learnt something here, so thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple way to implement what you're trying to do with the standard [form component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) (note that I explicitly didn't create a dedicated form type!).

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use AppBundle\Entity\Patient;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('patient', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'placeholder' => '--- Select ---',
                'class' => Patient::class,
                'choice_label' => function (Patient $patient) {
                    return sprintf(
                        '%s, %s',
                        $patient->getLastname(),
                        $patient->getFirstname()
                    );
                },
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
            ])
            ->getForm()
            ->handleRequest($request)
        ;

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var $selected Patient */
            $selected = $form->get('patient')->getData();
            dump($selected);
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

the view being:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button>Find results</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

I understand that the form component (especially [form customization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)) has it's learning curve, but ultimately, if you want to use symfony fully you'll end up using  it anyway (why reinvent the wheel). So the sooner you start with it the better.

Comment: Thank you, this is extra-helpful! I think I will use this way to solve this kind of problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

For mapped field

```
public function yourAction(Request $request){
        $patient = new Patient();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PatientType', $patient);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
         $patientId = $patient->getId();
        }
}
```

If you need to get a non mapped field (field that's not a Patient property)

```
public function yourAction(Request $request){
            $patient = new Patient();
            $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\PatientType', $patient);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted())
            {
             $patientCustomField = $form['customField']->getData();
            }
    }
```

Comment: patientId is not callable with form use `$patient->getPatientId()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but does it mean it can't work if form is defined inside of view? I was going for that option.

Comment: @BiljanaM. Try to add action in twig

Comment: In your twig template, if you try to use the form_start() twig function, what will be the name attribute of your form ?